# Console class in java Exception in reading password

Tags: java

i am trying to use Console class in java. with this code

```
import java.io.Console;
public class ConsoleClass {
public static void main(String[] args){
    Console c=System.console();
    char[] pw;
    pw=c.readPassword("%s","pw :");
    for(char ch:pw){
        c.format("%c",ch);
    }
    c.format("\n");
    MyUtility mu =new MyUtility();
    while(true){
        String name=c.readLine("%s", "input?: ");
        c.format("output: %s \n",mu.doStuff(name));

    }

  } 
}
class MyUtility{
String doStuff(String arg1){
    return "result is " +arg1;
}
}
```

here i am getting NullPointerException when i tried to run in netbeans but i am not getting any Exception when tried to run in cmd  with out netbeans IDE.Why?

Comment: Do you get a stack trace indicating what line is causing the null pointer exception?

Comment: System.console() returns null if there is no console. See here: http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.com/2010/09/java-systemconsole-ides-and-testing.html

Comment: @Michael McGowan i am getting at pw=c.readPassword("%s","pw :");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consoles are typically associated with processes that run independently of frameworks.  They are a means of interfacing a process's standard input and output with a shell.  If your classes are running as a component of a larger framework, the framework may own the console, and your program might not have a console at all.

There are other conditions and techniques to launch a program without a console.  They are typically used when the destruction of the console is guaranteed to occur, but you want the program detached in such a manner that the console's destruction doesn't signal the program's termination.

As such, you cannot guarantee the existence of a console; but, if you are going to run your program in an environment where the console is likely to be present, you should take advantage of it.

Answer (score 4):

`static Console console()
Returns the unique Console object associated with the current Java virtual machine, if any.`

**If any.**

> http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html

Comment: i understood why it will return NUllPointerException. But i have a doubt why this Console class was introduced in java 6 as there are so many alternatives

Comment: @satheesh - The console class is a neat way of providing console interaction if one exists, much better than using System.out and wrapping up System.in in an InputStreamReader than a BufferedReader. No, Java can't always guarantee a console will be in place, but if you just deploy your application to an environment where a console exists then it makes a huge amount of sense to use this class.

Answer (score 0):

`System.console()` returns a `Console` instance [if a console is associated with the process](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#console%28%29). - Running under NetBeans you likely don't have an associated console.